# Dividir os resultados de uma consulta utilizando mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, fetch

Preciso que seja mostrado em uma página um resultado com nomes de professores, uma linha horizontal `<hr>` a cada cinco nomes. Já tentei com `for` e com `foreach` mas não obtive sucesso. Queria saber se isso é possível e se for como posso resolver isso. Abaixo um fragmento do código que estou utilizando para exibir todos os nomes atualmente.

```
   $sel = "select prof from tblprof";
$qry = mysqli_query ($conn, $sel);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
   echo "Prof: ".$row['prof']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: O mais fácil é criar um contador de quantos itens você já exibiu e quando esse valor for múltiplo de 5 exibir o `<hr>`. Quer tentar? É tão simples quanto parece.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acho que a forma mais simples é como o colega citou, um contador checando se é múltiplo de 5. Segue exemplo:

```
$dados = array(
'Joao'=>'Biologia',
'Julieta'=>'Dança',
'Mateus'=>'Programação',
'Maria'=>'História',
'Paulo'=>'Música',
'Joao1'=>'Biologia1',
'Julieta1'=>'Dança1',
'Mateus1'=>'Programação1',
'Maria1'=>'História1',
'Paulo1'=>'Música1',
'Joao2'=>'Biologia2',
'Julieta2'=>'Dança2',
'Mateus2'=>'Programação2',
'Maria2'=>'História2',
'Paulo2'=>'Música2'

 );

 $cont = 0;
foreach($dados as $i => $k){

  echo $i ."  => " . $k . "<br>";
  $cont+=1;
  if($cont % 5 == 0){
     echo "<hr/>";
  }
 }
```

Flws

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu precisava.